# Can we able to add two Authorization header with same name in Jmeter header manager?

Tags: jmeter

I am facing 1 issue in jmeter header manager.
I need to add 
1."key=Authorization" with bearer key word in value "value=Bearer ${Token}"
2."key=Authorization" with out bearer key word in value "value=${Token}".

Is it possible to add 2 key with same name?
Or any other solution is there?

Errors getting:
1.)If I give both key and value in header-412- precondition.
2.)If I give 1 key and value with bearer-401 unauthorised.
3.)If I give 1 key and value with out bearer-400 Bad request.

I tried by adding 2 header manager one in global and one under http sampler.

Comment: Add Header Manager as a child below the request. I guess you have added two header manager in the root of the test plan.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2) document,

> A sender MUST NOT generate multiple header fields with the same field
> name in a message unless either the entire field value for that
> header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]
> or the header field is a well-known exception (as noted below).

> A recipient MAY combine multiple header fields with the same field
> name into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the
> the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to
> the combined field value in order, separated by a comma.  The order
> in which header fields with the same field-name are received is
> therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field
> value; a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when
> forwarding a message.

You will get `400 bad requests` if you send 2 fields with the same name in the header.

```
Response code: 400
Response message: Bad Request
```